# How to use the like parameter of numpy.arange() function

Tags: numpy

Hi I have a doubt to use the like parameter in the numpy.arange() function.

```
numpy.arange([start, ]stop, [step, ]dtype=None, *, like=None)
```

Here i'm not sure how to use the 'like' parameter in the arange funtion.

Comment: It's a new feature (v 1.20).  Have you looked at the referenced `NEP35`?  Since you don't (apparently) understand the documentation (and I don't either), it doesn't apply to you.  Ignore it.

Comment: https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0035-array-creation-dispatch-with-array-function.html talks about dispatching when using packages like `Dask`, `CuPy` and `xarray`.  If you aren't using those, then ignore `like`.